# How to listen to a callback url to know when a request is made to it

Tags: php

I am developing a ussd app in php and I want to know how to listen to the callback url and also collect the data sent from the gateway to my app.

Comment: well, if some service calls the callback url, then the script will be executed. that's how you listen..

Comment: Thank you. The problem was resolved by the line of code below. $ussdRequest = json_decode(@file_get_contents('php://input'));

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about a "callback URL". It is like any other URL.

If you want to run PHP when it is hit, then put a PHP script at it.

e.g. if the callback URL is `http://example.com/example.php` then create `example.php` and put it in the root directory of the `example.com` HTTP server.